# modify the code so that your own name can be included in the last Pasadena plot's title

Tags: python

Getting an error when trying to modify the title not sure what the issue is...

```
# formatted string literal: will insert values of variable in braces
f'{station}, {year}: average temperature = {avg:.2f} C',  'created'

('PASADENA, 2018: average temperature = 19.46 C', 'created')

# show normals, records, and current year bands together

pp.figure(figsize=(15,4.5))

pp.fill_between(days, tmin_record, tmax_record, color=(0.92,0.92,0.89), step='mid')
pp.fill_between(days, tmin_normal, tmax_normal, color=(0.78,0.72,0.72))

pp.fill_between(days, thisyear['TMIN'], thisyear['TMAX'],
                color=(0.73,0.21,0.41), alpha=0.6, step='mid')

pp.axis(xmin=1, xmax=365, ymin=-15, ymax=50)

pp.title(f'{station}, {year}: average temperature = {avg:.2f} C', 'created');

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-1e0a70458093> in <module>
     
pp.axis(xmin=1, xmax=365, ymin=-15, ymax=50)
     

--->  pp.title(f'{station}, {year}: average temperature = {avg:.2f} C', 'created');

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in title(label, fontdict, loc, pad, **kwargs)

    @docstring.copy(Axes.set_title)

    def title(label, fontdict=None, loc=None, pad=None, **kwargs):
->     return gca().set_title(

           label, fontdict=fontdict, loc=loc, pad=pad, **kwargs)


~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in set_title(self, label, 
fontdict, loc, pad, **kwargs)

    211         title.update(default)

    212         if fontdict is not None:`

--> `enter code here`             title.update(fontdict)

             title.update(kwargs)

            return title

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in update(self, kwargs)

             # Update bbox last, as it depends on font properties.

             sentinel = object()  # bbox can be None, so use another sentinel.

-->         bbox = kwargs.pop("bbox", sentinel)

            super().update(kwargs)

             if bbox is not sentinel:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a minimal reproducible example. This is not it.

However, from the error message it seems pyplot cannot handle your formatted string:
`f'{station}, {year}: average temperature = {avg:.2f} C'`

Try to save it as a string first and then set title using that string.